# ScrollView content size

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I've a ScrollView that contains three view.

My intent is to make a ScrollView that has a particular geometric shape.
I want a vertical scrolling only if I am in the second view.

```
UIViewController* VC1=[[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController1" bundle:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:VC1];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:VC1.view];
    [VC1 didMoveToParentViewController:self];

UIViewController* VC2=[[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
[self addChildViewController:VC2];
[self.scrollView addSubview:VC2.view];
[VC2 didMoveToParentViewController:self];

CGRect VC2frame=VC2.view.frame;
VC2frame.origin.x=self.view.frame.size.width;
VC2.view.frame=VC2frame;

UIViewController* VC3=[[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController3" bundle:nil];
[self addChildViewController:VC3];
[self.scrollView addSubview:VC3.view];
[VC3 didMoveToParentViewController:self];

CGRect VC3frame=VC3.view.frame;
VC3frame.origin.x=self.view.frame.size.width;
VC3frame.origin.y=self.view.frame.size.height;
VC3.view.frame=VC3frame;

self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width*2, self.view.frame.size.height*2);
```

If I set the contentSize like above, it gives my another ( blank ) view under the first .

How can I try a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? This code adds ViewController2 and ViewController3 into a second scroll view (one on top of the other) and then adds the second scroll view to the original scroll view at the position at which you were originally adding ViewController2.

```
UIViewController* VC1=[[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController1" bundle:nil];
[self addChildViewController:VC1];
[self.scrollView addSubview:VC1.view];
[VC1 didMoveToParentViewController:self];

UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height * 2);
[self.scrollView addSubview:scroll];

UIViewController* VC2=[[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
[self addChildViewController:VC2];
[scroll addSubview:VC2.view];
[VC2 didMoveToParentViewController:self];

UIViewController* VC3=[[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController3" bundle:nil];
[self addChildViewController:VC3];
[scroll addSubview:VC3.view];
[VC3 didMoveToParentViewController:self];

CGRect VC3frame=VC3.view.frame;
VC3frame.origin.y=self.view.frame.size.height;
VC3.view.frame=VC3frame;

self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width*2, self.view.frame.size.height);
```